# How to access DB in AWS ( made with Ruby on rails ) from Android application?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, devise

I'm now trying to make a mobile application that asks users to put user account information to log in and get data from DB in AWS ( The web application is made in Ruby on Rails ).

The Ruby application uses Devise Gem currently. There are two ways of receiving user information: one is email and password and the other one is Google+ sign in.

As a support content, I also want to build a Android mobile application. This application should ask users to put user account information and get the only accessible data as a uniquely defined user.

How can I make this function? I'm now using Android Studio and if I can get the big picture, it would be really helpful!

Comment: So you have a ruby on rails web app and you want to create an android app which uses the same database... is that right?

Comment: yes yes!! The android application will also have login function and get the data from the AWS DB ( mostly get method )! Is there way to do this?

Comment: @sameera207 's answer should put you on the right path. You should look in to token authentication w/ Devise when authenticating via API.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access the DB directly from your mobile app (android in your case), You will have to built an `api` for this.

So the basic workflow would be

- you have an api endpoint say, `users/login`
- you go a post request with `user_name`, `password` to this api
  (ajax/json)
- login method will use `devise` to validate user information
- `api` will return an appropriate json response (Ex: user object as json)

So there are several ways of writing an api.

1 - easiest way would be to have a controller with namespce api Ex:

```
#app/controllers/api/login_controller.rb
controller Api::LoginController < ApplicationController
  def create 
     #some code to validate user input and response
  end  
end
```

2) more sustainable long term solution would be to use some kind of a `gem` to build it. [Grepe](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape) is once such gem which supports more useful features like `api versioning`